# Kube-controller-manager HPA counts unready pods and doesn't consider them for desiredReplica calculation

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-scaling, kube-controller-manager

**What happened:**

`HPA` does not scale up pods as expected after upgrade from kubernetes 1.10.6 to 1.12.8.
In below snippet, although the scaling metric is beyond the target value, Replicas count is not increasing.

```
NAME REFERENCE TARGETS MINPODS MAXPODS REPLICAS AGE
test-service-hpa Deployment/test-deploy 666m/600m 3 100 3 26d

test-deploy-5b985f9785-4znlb 1/2 Running 0 3h21m
test-deploy-5b985f9785-csld4 2/2 Running 0 10h
test-deploy-5b985f9785-tg52z 1/2 Running 0 3h18m
```

Its is because, `HPA` is not considering unready pods in `desiredReplica` calculation. In our use case, we mark pods as unready when the pod is handling traffic and we dont want any more traffic to be routed to this pod. I know the kubernets term `unready` pods is not very well used in our usecase. But just this behavior was working fine with kubernetes 1.10.6 and not in 1.12.8, would like to know if there is a workaround to fix it.

**What you expected to happen:**

`HPA` should consider `unready` pods as well while scaling up. Or need a flag to restore this behavior from 1.10.6.

**How to reproduce it** (as minimally and precisely as possible):

```
Create a simple deployment with minPod =3, maxPod=100.
```

Anything else we need to know?:

**Environment:**

```
Kubernetes version (use kubectl version): 1.12.8
OS (e.g: cat /etc/os-release): Ubuntu "18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
Kernel (e.g. uname -a): x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: can you share the deployment file, saved inside the kubernetes after you deployed it

Comment: @TusharMahajan, Thanks for the reply. The deployment file saved in kubernetes is pretty long. Can you please tell me which part of deployment you are interested in

Comment: just display the resources section of your deployment file

Comment: Just to understand correctly what you are trying to achieve. 
You are intentionally putting pod out of the pool (with marking it as not ready) and then you would 
like HPA to count your 'not ready` pod and not create a new one on its place?